# What drives the "reopen" audit queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I saw this question on "reopen votes" as an audit question:

[Communication between nested directives](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223006/communication-between-nested-directives)

The question is a month old, despite not eliciting a single answer or comment.  IMO, it's too broad and oddly worded to be a useful question.  Which seemed like a good reason to close it, although I'm not sure if the question was ever closed at all.

Which leads me to wonder about the mechanism by which the audit questions are selected, both in general an for this question in particular?

- Are review questions chosen manually by site admins, as stellar examples?
- Are they selected from questions that passed a given review-able action, and then passed with a certain percentage of consensus among the review questions?
- Or is each review queue different, with "re-open" selecting questions that were never closed?

Comment: it's driven by straightforward brainless algorithm, having sufficiently high score and being not too old as main ingredients to decide if question is OK for audit. It even can happen that [post you voted down and close is shown to you as known good audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)

Comment: Reading the comment you linked, @psubsee2003 alluded that reopen audits have a more complicated mechanism behind them than the first-post queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions are picked automatically from questions in the past time period (I think its 1 month and at least some minimum number of days) that have 5 or more upvotes (but less than 15), no downvotes, no close votes, some minimum number of views.

Yes, this does cause problems with soft questions that have a number of upvotes on them that are borderline.  This is a known 'issue', but realize that audits are there to serve two purposes:

- Catch roboreviewers who say *everything* is a certain way
- Help people reconsider what they chose and why to help guide reviews to match the community consensus.

As I understand it, the second bullet point is a distant second to the first one and so the borderline cases really aren't as big of an issue as people who fail the review audit consider them to be.

From MSO:

- [How do we select audits for Reopen review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168381/213963)
- [Failed a Reopen Question audit — sure looks like “Not a real question” to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/213963)